# simplexml_load_file errors worked a couple of times then stopped;

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having a problem loading my xml file using simplexml_load_file(), would really appreciate some help. The code worked a couple of times and after that all I got was unable to open file  even though the file exists  Thanks.

```
<?php
echo 'starting read<br>';
////////////////////////////////////
 //$categories=$_POST["categories"];
 //$project=$_POST["project"];
//$camera=$_POST["camera"];
//$description=$_POST["description"];
//$num=$_POST["val"];
///////////////////////////////////
$categories='a';
$project='a';
$camera='a'; 
$description='a';
$num=2;
//////////////////////////////////
$data=$categories.'<br />'.$project.'<br />'.$camera.'<br />'.$description;
echo $data;
$file = "main.xml";
//checking if file exists
 if(!file_exists($file))
  {echo'<br> file does not exist<br>';
  }
 else 
 echo '<br> file exists <br>';

// load file
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("Unable to load XML file!");


// access XML data

$val=$xml->settings->imagesPage->imagesGallery->pageTitle[$num];
echo $val;
$xml->settings->imagesPage->imagesGallery->pageTitle[$num]=$data;
file_put_contents($file, $xml->asXML());

  echo  '<br>'. $desc.'\n';

?>
```

this is the xml file structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <content>
       <settings>
          <imagespage>
             <imagesGallery>
                <pageTitle><![CDATA[<br>SED UT PERSPI<br>CANON 124<br>LOREM IPSUM<br>DOLOR SIT AMET]]></pageTitle>
                 <pageTitle><![CDATA[<br>SED UT PERSPI<br>CANON 124<br>LOREM IPSUM<br>DOLOR SIT AMET]]></pageTitle>
                  <pageTitle><![CDATA[<br>SED UT PERSPI<br>CANON 124<br>LOREM IPSUM<br>DOLOR SIT AMET]]></pageTitle>
                   <pageTitle><![CDATA[<br>SED UT PERSPI<br>CANON 124<br>LOREM IPSUM<br>DOLOR SIT AMET]]></pageTitle>
                    <pageTitle><![CDATA[<br>SED UT PERSPI<br>CANON 124<br>LOREM IPSUM<br>DOLOR SIT AMET]]></pageTitle>
              </imagesGallery>
             </imagespage>
         </settings>
     </content>
```

I have also made sure that allow_url_fopen is set to ON

Comment: Did you get an error message? If yes, what?

Comment: no error messages all that was displayed is "Unable to load XML file",

Comment: give proper path to your XML file.

Comment: no error messages all that was displayed is "Unable to load XML file", as you can see i used the file exists function to check if the file path was set correctly; the output from file_exists($file) is true,the error is  Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: main.xml:370: parser error : error parsing attribute name in C:\wamp\www\grab.php on line 27

Comment: @thinking monkey I've set the file to a variable $file and fileexists($file)  returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tlenss thank you i corrected `$desc` it was supposed to be `$data`, the other error you found was a typo i made on the webpage

My problem was that my xml file loaded a correctly the first few times but then threw errors saying it was unable to load  On closer inspection of `var_dump($xml)` i found the problem was that simpleXML cannot handle cdata properly

so i loaded my file like this

```
$xml = simpleXML_load_file($url,"SimpleXMLElement",LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

loading like this `$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)` is fine if your document doesnot have a cdata section

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo on line 34

```
$xml->settings->imagesPage->imagesGallery->pageTitle[$num]=$data;
```

Should be

```
$xml->settings->imagespage->imagesGallery->pageTitle[$num]=$data;
```

And besides that an undefined error at the end for `$desc`. It's not set!